# Unable to Disable "petstore" URL in SpringDoc OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am currently working on a project using Spring Boot 3.1.2, SpringDoc OpenAPI Starter WebMvc UI 2.1.0, and JDK 17. I have encountered an issue where I am unable to disable the "petstore" URL in the SpringDoc OpenAPI documentation. It seems that the configuration properties in my YAML file are not taking effect.

The "**petstore**" URL is appearing in the SpringDoc OpenAPI UI, even though I have tried to disable it using the configuration properties in my application.yml file.

**Versions:**

Spring Boot: 3.1.2
SpringDoc OpenAPI Starter WebMvc UI: 2.1.0
JDK: 17

**Are there any known issues or compatibility concerns with the versions I am using (Spring Boot 3.1.2, SpringDoc OpenAPI Starter WebMvc UI 2.1.0, and JDK 17) that might be causing this problem?**